# Looping through files with bashscript not working

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I have this code which works:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

for entry in "$DIR"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

But when I try to do this,

```
for entry in "$DIR/Images"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

then my script tries to access a file with the name $DIR/Images/*

When I do this in attempt to fix the problem:

```
for entry in "$(DIR/Images)"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

the script prints out all files in the root directory of my mac. How Do I make my script loop through all files in $DIR/Images/?

assuming of course that Images exists

Comment: How about `for entry in "$DIR"/Images/*` ?

Comment: That worked thanks! Also, in my script I am running another script. Do you know how I would pause my current script and wait till the other one is done running?

Comment: Sounds like an excellent new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for entry in "$DIR"/Images/*
```

works, per your comment.

I'm not convinced there is a difference between `"$DIR/Images"/*` and `"$DIR"/Images/*`.

```
for entry in "$DIR/Images/*"
```

Will not work, because asterisks are not expanded in quotes, and `$DIR/Images/*` will not work if `$DIR` contains spaces.

However,

```
mkdir "folder with spaces"
a="folder with spaces"
mkdir "$a"/bc
touch "$a"/bc/def.txt
echo "$a"/bc/*
  >> folder with spaces/bc/def.txt
echo "$a/bc"/*
  >> folder with spaces/bc/def.txt
```

I.e., both ways work on my machine.